# How to convert table to DragDrop with php

Tags: html, mysql

I have a table to show my datas. I am getting the datas from my mysql database. Nowadays, I want to re order(drag-drop) entries and update my database and show the datas with ordered.

This is my table;

```html
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <?php while($data = mysql_fetch_array('result'){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$data['engword'];?></td>
     <td align="left"><a href= "/post/<?={$data['slug']};?>"><?={$data['title']};?></a></td>
        </tr>
 <tr>
            <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?=stripslashes($data["tags"]);?></td>
 </tr>
      <?php
       }
      ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How to convert this table draggable style.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [repo](https://github.com/senocak/PHP-JS-Drag-Drop-Order-Entries) that I made. It should work